# Safari webkit transition flicker

Tags: safari, webkit, transition

I am experiencing flickering when fading in elements using webkit transition opacity.

The issue only occurs in Safari but it is really glitchy.

I have tried `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` and `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);`
but none are working, does anyone have any ideas?

http://www.timbretday.com

Comment: has anyone encountered the same issue?

Comment: solved it, adding keyframes in the CSS stopped the flicker

Answer (score 0):

solved it, adding keyframes in the CSS stopped the flicker